# Show that $x$ has order $8$ in $\frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2+2)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I know that because $x^2+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$, then the quotient ring is a field. I'm pretty sure that the order of this quotient ring is $5*5*5 -1 =124 = 2*2*31$, because we have $5$ choices for the coefficients on $x^0,x^1$, and $x^2$, and then we have to ignore the zero element.

However, if $x$ has order $8$, then wouldn't the fact that $8 \nmid 124$ contradict Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: Why is the order $5^3 - 1$? the degree of the polynomial is 2

Comment: Oops. You're right, that makes no sense.

Comment: The $x^2$ power will not be part of this basis, since $x^2 = -2$ in the quotient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily verify that the order of the given element is 8: just compute all powers and check that the first one that yields 1 is the 8th power.

On the other hand, you're right when you say that the polynomial in the quotient is irreducible (there are no square roots of -2 in $\Bbb F_5$), but since the degree of this polynomial is 2, the quotient field would have $5^2 = 25$ elements, among which $25 - 1 = 24$ are invertible. Notice that since $8\mid 24$, there is no contradiction at all.

Comment: Ah. So my mistake was in calculating the order of the group. That makes sense; thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help :). Nevertheless, you never needed to calculate the order of the group, in order to calculate the order of $x$ you simply multiply $x$ by itself until you hit $1$, but it's good you went further and analyzed it even made sense

Answer (score 0):

$-2$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{5}$, hence $x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ is a finite field isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$. The multiplicative part of a finite field is a cyclic group, hence every element of $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+2)$ has an order that is a divisor of $24=25-1$. In particular, $x^2=-2$ implies $x^4=4$ and $x^8=1$, so the order of $x$ is exactly $8$.